# Função jQuery com fancybox - Estou com problema de refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Ao abrir ou fechar a `fancybox` (sou programador **php** mas iniciante em **Javascript** com **jquery**), a minha página dá um *refresh* e volta para o topo do conteúdo perdendo o foco do lugar que o conteúdo se encontrava ao acionar a `fancybox`. A ação pode ser vista aqui (http://santins.com.br/_z/holcim) clicando em qualquer link que abre a `fancybox` e o código que estou usando é este:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        closeClick: true,
        padding: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 'auto',
        arrows: true,
        autoSize: false,
        nextClick: true,
            'ajax': {
            dataFilter: function (data) {
                return $(data).find('#primary')[0];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olhando o seu site, como não há uma referencia de posição utilizando a barra de endereço mais especificamente a área de `hash` do `window.location` o que acontece é que quando você entra no seu `fancybox` ele acaba por eliminar o scrollbar, levando o valor para 0.

Uma solução é na hora em que a pessoa clicar, antes de exibir seu `fancybox`, você armazenar em uma variável de contexto a posição do `scroll` e ao fechar, você aplicar a navegação pro scroll que salvou, levando a pessoa de volta a posição original.

Primeiro vamos pegar os botões que tem `fancybox` e dar uma função para armazenar o valor do `scrollTop` quando clicado:

```
window.lastScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // Vai iniciar em zero;
// Quando clicar no fancybox vamos salvar um novo valor
$('a.fancybox').on('click', function () {
    window.lastScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

Agora quando você sair do `fancybox` tem que retornar ao valor armazenado, então nas sua configurações, tem que adicionar `onClosed` *handler*.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        // ...
        onClosed: function () {
            // Ao fechar leva de volta a posição armazenada anterior do scrollTop
            $(window).scrollTop(window.lastScrollTop);
        },
        // ...
    });
});
```

Utilizei uma variável global `lastScrollTop` pois não sei como seu código foi escrito e não sei como isolar o contexto pra este caso. Mas não recomendo o uso de variáveis globais.

Outra maneira mais genérica também é possível, no lugar de adicionar o evento de click nas ancoras, é utilizar o `onStart` *handler* do fancybox, teoricamente é chamado antes de aplicar seu efeito que vai eliminar o `scrollTop`, ficaria assim:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var lastScrollTop;
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        // ...
        onStart: function () {
            // Armazenando o scrollTop antes de iniciar o processo scrollTop
            lastScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        },
        onClosed: function () {
            // Ao fechar leva de volta a posição armazenada anterior do scrollTop
            $(window).scrollTop(lastScrollTop);
        },
        // ...
    });
});
```

Desta maneira é possível utilizar variável de contexto não expondo nenhuma variável global.

Comment: Poderia me ajudar a fazer isso Gabriel?

Comment: Está ai uma solução que deve ajudar-lhe @marcosvinicius

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância em não saber se devo colocar alguma coisa nesses 3 pontinhos (...) ...

Comment: os três pontinhos é só pra exemplificar que esse trecho de código fica entre o seu código, pode ficar antes ou depois. Tenta colocar depois do `autoSize` e antes do `nextClick` sem incluir os `...` claro, pois são propriedades de um objeto literal que você está passando como parâmetro do método `fancybox`.

Answer (score 2):

Eu resolvi o problema com o seguinte código:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
  padding: 0,
  helpers: {
    overlay: {
      locked: false
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: também funciona